# Meteor stopped auto refreshing the browser when user logs in

Tags: meteor

I'm using the latest Meteor + latest React. A couple of days ago it stopped auto-refreshing on file change in Chrome. I opened Safari and it worked there, so I continued my development using it. Today Safari stopped auto-refreshing as well. There are no errors in any of the consoles (meteor or browser). I do get `Client modified -- refreshing (x12)` messages in Meteor console, but nothing else happens. I removed the `.meteor/local/build` folder and restarted Meteor but that didn't help. Looking for any pointers to fix this. Thank you in advance

Update:
It does work when in incognito or in regular browser window but only if I'm not logged in to the site. Once I log in, there are three local storage items created: Meteor.userId, Meteor.loginToken, and Meteor.loginTokenExpires. And auto-refresh no longer works. If I log out, auto-refresh starts working again.